# Extensions of an ideal-theoretic criterion for a monoid to be BF

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, factorization-theory

Let $H$ be a multiplicatively written, *commutative* monoid. We denote by $H^\times$ the *set of units* (or *invertible elements*) of $H$, and by $\mathcal A(H)$ the *set of atoms* (or *irreducible elements*) of $H$, where $a \in H$ is an atom if $a \notin H^\times$ and there do not exist $x, y \in H \setminus H^\times$ for which $a = xy$.

We take an *ideal* of $H$ to be a set $I \subseteq H$ such that $I = I H$ (these are often referred to as *$s$-ideals* in factorization theory), and we say that an ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $H$ is prime if $H \setminus \mathfrak p$ is a submonoid of $H$.

On the other hand, we call $H$ a *BF-monoid* if, for every $x \in H \setminus H^\times$, the *set of lengths of $x$*, viz., the set of all $k \in \mathbf N^+$ such that $x = a_1 \cdots a_k$ for some $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in \mathcal A(H)$, is finite and non-empty.

The following theorem is well known (at least in some circles), and can be used, together with other classical results in commutative algebra, to prove that every Noetherian commutative domain is BF (i.e., the multiplicative monoid of its non-zero elements is BF):

> **Theorem.** Assume $H$ is cancellative, and let $\Omega$ be a set of non-empty prime ideals of $H$ such that $\bigcap_{n \ge 1} \mathfrak p^n = \emptyset$ for all $\mathfrak p \in \Omega$. In addition, suppose that, for every $x \in H \setminus H^\times$, the set $\Omega_x := \{\mathfrak p \in \Omega: x \in \mathfrak p\}$ is finite and non-empty. Then $H$ is a BF-monoid.

My questions are:

> **Qs.** (1) What is known about generalizations of the above theorem to non-commutative or non-cancellative monoids? (2) What about an example showing that, in the above theorem, we cannot just assume that $\Omega$ is non-empty and $\Omega_x$ is finite (either empty or not) for all $x \in H \setminus H^\times$?

*Edit (Apr 28, 2017).* The following was originally a comment (dating back to  Apr 16), but it's probably better to remove it from the comments and include it here in the OP (which is what I'm doing):

Q2 is kind of trivial. Indeed, let $H$ be the direct product of $(\mathbf N^+,\cdot)$ and $(\mathbf Q_{\ge 0},+)$. Then $H$ is not even atomic, because $H^\times=\{(1,0)\}$ and no element of $H$ of the form $(1,x)$ with $x \in \mathbf Q^+$ is an atom. Nevertheless, if $\mathbf P$ is the set of prime elements of $(\mathbf N^+,\cdot)$, then $$\Gamma_p :=\{np:n \in \mathbf N^+\} \times \mathbf Q_{\ge 0}$$ is a prime ideal of $H$ for every $p \in \mathbf P$, and the family $\Omega:=\{\Gamma_p: p \in \mathbf P\}$ provides an answer to Q2.

Comment: This is not the usual definition of semigroup ideal.

Comment: For non commutative monoids would you use two sided or one sided ideals?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg That's part of the question! It's not so clear to me what "the right generalization" should be in this case. As for the definition of an ideal, there was a typo in the origianl version of the OP.